# How to replace local camera video stram by a remote one

Tags: facebook, video-streaming

I want to make the facebook app stream my laptop screen (as live video), my idea is to change source stream of the phone camera to a remote stream from a laptop, any idea on how to do this (with an app or programatically)?

Comment: Why not stream directly from the laptop?

Comment: the facebook (original app) do not permit streaming from browser (am I wrong?)

Comment: Oh, I just see, you can only stream via the app. Well, in theory you could overwrite the framebuffer of the camera but only in theory. When an app gains control over the camera, it's directly interfacing with it, meaning it is  very hard to replace its current image. I don't think such a thing is possible on Android.

Comment: Oh, apparently it works: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-stream-to-facebook-live.391/

Comment: Sadely, It seems I have not yet this feature on my (newly created) account!

Comment: It's only possible for sites, not for private accounts.